# finding a proper event for new appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm creating a simple page builder
I use this JQuery code to append new 'skill bar' to an element

```js
 var percent = 0;
 $("#progressbar").click(function() {
   var title = document.getElementById('pb-title').value;
   percent = document.getElementById('pb-percent').value;
   var item = '<div class="skills-section"><div class="skills-progress"><p>' + title + '<span>' + percent + '</span></p><div class="meter nostrips wp"><span></span></div></div></div>';
   $(SelectedElement).append(item);
   percent += '%';
 });
```

, and skill bar has an load effect , but after I create this new skill bar' effect doesn't work and as I search for it , I use on() to solve that problem , and It's solve right now by this code

```js
 $(document).on('what should be here ?!', '.meter > span', function() {
   $(this)
     .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
     .width(0)
     .animate({
       width: percent
     }, 1200);
 });
```

but my new problem is that the effect should run after the element appending but it doesn't do that ... I don't know which event should be called in on() first parameter ...
I tested click and it works (effect shows perfectly) but I want it to be automaticly after element creation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are creating the new elements in your own code, you can trigger any event you want :

```
var percent = 0;
$("#progressbar").click(function() {
  var title = document.getElementById('pb-title').value;
  percent = document.getElementById('pb-percent').value;
  var item = '<div class="skills-section"><div class="skills-progress"><p>' + title + '<span>' + percent + '</span></p><div class="meter nostrips wp"><span></span></div></div></div>';
  $(SelectedElement).append(item);
  percent += '%';

  $(this).trigger('myevent');
});

$(document).on('myEvent', ...);
```

In some recent browsers, you can use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect changes in the DOM. But some browers does not support it.